# How can I cite something which doesn't have any related research-paper published?

Tags: publications, citations

Suppose, I want to cite a framework written in Python (in my case it is: [Keras](https://keras.io/)) that doesn't have any related research paper published.

I saw other papers used in-line URLs, URLs in the citation,

> Falbel D, Allaire JJ, and Chollet F. R interface to ‘Keras’. https://keras.rstudio.com/index.html

and even arXiv. Others used the [so-called Hands-on books](https://books.google.pl/books?hl=en&lr=&id=20EwDwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PP1&dq=keras%20&ots=lIczcn9PW4&sig=-qOywXmWh86DIYc-elEmuxiHQzc&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=keras&f=false) which are not academic at all. Others wrote something like the following:

> (6) Chollet, F.et al. Keras; 2015.

The above is actually referring to the framework itself, not any research paper or URL.

I guess, none of these are recognized by the [*ISI Web of Science*](https://www.webofscience.com/wos/woscc/basic-search).
ISI is a well-established company that provides these counts. Their results really matter. But they count neither *arXive* nor URLs.

How can I cite it so that my paper is not excluded from the *ISI Web of Science* citation counting system?

Comment: But why would you care whether Web of Science recognizes the citation or not? Are you citing Keras for the benefit of Web of Science, or for the benefit of your readers? If the latter, I'd just add the URL to the github page and live happily.

Comment: @Anyon, the benefit of myself.

Comment: Your [most recent edit](https://academia.stackexchange.com/revisions/182393/4) confuses me. Is the situation 1) You're writing a paper that will hopefully get published in a journal indexed by WoS, and your paper cites a framework or software that does not have an associated research paper, so you worry the creators of that framework won't get enough credit? Or is it 2) you are authoring such a framework yourself and want the full citation credit for it? In the latter case, as things stand currently, the best approach is probably to publish an accompanying software paper.

Comment: @Anyon, Case #1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This exact question is [addressed in their FAQ](https://keras.io/getting_started/faq/#how-should-i-cite-keras). As of the time of this answer, their suggestion is:

> Please cite Keras in your publications if it helps your research. Here is an example BibTeX entry:
>
> ```
> @misc{chollet2015keras,
>  title={Keras},
>  author={Chollet, Fran\c{c}ois and others},
>  year={2015},
>  howpublished={\url{https://keras.io}},
> }
> ```

Alternative citation methods are listed on the [github issues page](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/247).